# Use TREATAS to pass constant to a measure with CALCULATE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a what-if parameter in a PowerBI desktop report called `'Default Target'[Default Target]` which ranges from 0.8 to 1 in 0.001 increments.

```
Default Target = GENERATESERIES(0.8, 1.0, 0.001)
```

The what if parameter also built a measure for me called `[Default Target Value]` which is meant to return the `SELECTEDVALUE()` of the parameter, or its default value as the alternate result:

```
Default Target Value = SELECTEDVALUE('Default Target'[Default Target], 0.94)
```

I want to present `[MyFancyMeasure]`, but prescribe certain `[Default Targets]` and load them into table columns for comparison. So I built several measures to use `CALCULATE` and `TREATAS` to get the results, as in this example:

```
CAR_86 = CALCULATE( [MyFancyMeasure], TREATAS({{0.86}},'Default Target'[Default Target]) )
```

but this didn't give me the expected result (I was expecting it to use 86% as the selected value of `[Default Target]`, not 94%).

Instead, it returns all rows based on the `<alternateResult>` of the selectedvalue measure:
[image: screenshot of undesirable result]

- Why is `[CAR_86]` not aligning with the actual selectedvalue of the what-if parameter slicer, and also not aligning to the filtered value from the `TREATAS` function?
- How can I effectively pass a constant to `[MyFancyMeasure]` so I don't have to rewrite the entire measure for each constant I want to present?

Also: I tried to filter the default target table in the calculate like this but it does the same thing:

```
CAR_86 = CALCULATE( [Default Target Value], FILTER(ALL('Default Target'),[Default Target]=0.86) )
```

Comment: regarding the first question - it seems to be precision issue, for me 0.8600000000000001 worked instead of 0.86, i.e. `CAR_86 = CALCULATE( [Default Target Value], TREATAS({0.8600000000000001} , 'Default Target'[Default Target]))`

Comment: @Stachu That was precisely the issue - It behaves as expected once I account for this. Thank you!